# undefined source must start with "https://" or "//"

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, amp-html

Hi we have set up Google AMP for our site. We have implemented an Adobe Analytics tag but getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: undefined source must start with
>   "https://" or "//" or be relative and served from either https or from
>   localhost.

I understand the issue stems from the base value of the URL:

```
{"requests": {"base": "http://${trackingServer}/b/ss/${accounts}/1/AMP-0.1/s${random}","pageView":
```

Problem is our site does not use a secure protocol. Would there be any issues if we change the base to either https or // as specified by the error? Would like some advice before I request the developers to make the changes.

Comment: Loading https content from a http site should be possible. It seems that would fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 3rd party cookies (tracking server ending in `omtrdc.net` or `2o7.net`) for Adobe Analytics, you will likely be using the same tracking server for both secure and non-secure pages. In that case, you can use the either `https://` or just `//`.

If you're using 1st party cookies (tracking server with *your* domain), there will likely be a different tracking server that you'll use for secure vs. non-secure.